# Angular JS API refresh in 100 milliseconds

Tags: angularjs

I want to refresh the API every 100 milli seconds ,can anyone help.
code takes data from api and displays in the table. Backend is updated from different sources ,so we are supposed to refresh the data every 100ms.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Includes</title>
<style>
table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AngularJS Cycle count application</h2>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr>
<th>Item Number </th>
<th>UPC Number</th>
<th>Count Qnty</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.ITEM }}</td>
<td>{{ x.UPC}}</td>
<td>{{ x.QNTY}}</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">                
</script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get("http://54.244.108.186:4000/api/cc_detail")
.then(function (response) {

$scope.names = response.data.item_upc;
});

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not use SO as a "write this code for me" service.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to refresh your screen based on back end updates then ideally you should try to use HTML5 Server Sent Events rather then hitting a particular API every 100 milliseconds. Hitting the api every 100 milliseconds would create a new thread on the server to handle the request causing a bottleneck for other requests.....you would kind of be simulating a DOS attack.

HTML5 event source will create one connection with the server and would allow the server to push updates to the client whenever required instead of making multiple requests.

Refer to link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp for more on HTML5 Server Sent Events

Comment: Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this post ??